# Get 3 words count in string

Tags: php

I am trying to get word frequency for 3 words only in a string. For example:

$string = "This is a sample text. It is a sample text used as an example.";

I want output:

"is a sample" (2)

"a sample text" (2)

.... and so on

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it home work for SO ?...

Comment: Tell us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @X.L.Ant What I have tried so far is far away from a good result. I did some preg_match_all which doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Explode the sentence with a space as the delimiter and loop through.

```
<?php
$string = "This is a sample text. It is a sample text used as an example.";
$arr = explode(' ',$string);
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
echo $arr[$i]." ".$arr[$i+1]." ".$arr[$i+2]."<br>";
$i++;
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
This is a
is a sample
a sample text.
sample text. It
text. It is
It is a
is a sample
a sample text
sample text used
.....
```

Comment: thanks for help but this does not get frequency of the 3 words in the original string

Comment: EDIT: posting doesn't work in reply, but it gets some bad words (1 word only) at the end

Comment: Edit it on your question.

Comment: even if I did so, your method doesn't work sir it doesn't ouput any numeric value since it has no way of counting them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "This is a sample text. It is a sample text used as an example.";
$words = preg_split('/\W/', $string);
$wordsPerRow = 3;


$offset = 0;
while ($offset < count($words)) {
    print implode(' ', array_slice($words, $offset, $wordsPerRow)).PHP_EOL;
    $offset += $wordsPerRow;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir but this outputs the string itself again, any help ?

Comment: As Shankar wrote, edit your question if you think something is missing. I gave you what you asked for.

Comment: my question already says it wants the frequency which is stated sir: I want output: "is a sample" (2)... can you see the brackets sir which says (2) ?

Comment: Please rephrase your specification to make it clear what output you want, which frequency your need counted. "Word frequency for 3 words" is always 3 so I assumed it wasn't what you really meant. Now that it turned out my assumption was wrong, I can only ask you to rephrase your specification to make it clear what you wanted.